# JAVA Graphics2D Add Padding

Tags: java, awt, paint, graphics2d

I am woring on a JAVA project and need to add transparent padding so the final output looks clean. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent object, int width, int height) {

    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
    g.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0,
                                       width - 1,
                                       height + 1,
                                       10, 10));
    g.setColor(lineColor);
    g.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, height - 1 , width, height - 1));
}
```

The code above creates a rounded rectangle, similar to Tabs you see on a web browser or an different applications. The problem is.. there is no blank space between the tabs. How do I pragmatically add 10 pixels padding to right of the Graphics2D object?

Comment: Can't you simply reduce the `width` of the area you painting by `10` pixels, something like `g.draw(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width - 11, height + 1, 10, 10));` for example?

Comment: I did try it but it doesn't look so good. It's better to add 10 pixels... this way no matter what the width of the Graphics2D object is, it will work well for all.

Comment: Given the fact that this is a custom process, it's difficult to provide a suggestion. Any change you can do a runnable example?